# In .NET converting a string with \n (new line) and other special characters to HTML and respecting the formatting?

Tags: .net, html, string

in .NET, is there a way to convert a string with \n (new line) and other special characters to HTML respecting the formatting?
If not I could write my own method to replace \n with < BR/>' put I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with the <br/> method? Is it because you would rather div's/p's?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I wasjust wondering if there was a built in method provided by MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better way, for example if you want to have a label's text take up two lines, you must manual add `<br />` to the text of the label were you want the break to be.